# Emulating sensors

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a type of sensor that can be emulated on an Android emulator, or must I use an external tool for any sensor (or a device of course)? What I mean is just like I can use the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to simulate telephony or location, maybe there is a sensor (like light or temperature) that I can also control and send arguments to the emulator.
Thanks.

Comment: With "must I use an external tool for any sensor (or a device of course)", do you refer to something like http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation ? Or will that answer your question? If that does not answer your question I guess you could always use that source code as a base for creating a custom extension yourself.

Comment: What I meant to ask is whether the Android SDK comes with some support for emulating sensors or I must download a separate tool for it. I guess I'll have to use a separate tool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use **SensorSimulator** for this purpose.[Here the link to download it..and also helps how to use the sensorsimulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator)